# Communication between android application to android application in different mobiles

Tags: java, android, sockets, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating an application which need to communicate with 2 different android applications(may be combination of IOS and android in future) :

1. First application will request for the service and
2. If second application accept the request then particular details need to be sent(it is not chat application though) .

I tried using c2dm(aka GCM) but the service is not reliable to be precise.

My application is similar to uber/ola requesting type when a customer request for ride,the request will be go to nearby riders who accepts it, that rider details will be provided to customer.

please suggest any third party api or any solution if possible

Thanks in advance

Comment: i am using parse as baas so i have very limited options please help based on that

Comment: Integrate your app with PubNub which provides the feature and it is reliable. [link](https://www.pubnub.com)

Comment: Thanks Raghavendra i am trying that option but do we have any other solution where programmatically we will solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, if you need in programmatic you can use MQTT protocol or socket programming.

Comment: Thanks for the details letme try MQTT if u have any example please share here it will be definitely helpful